# Front object child in RelativeLayout in XML-resourses

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got a custom RelativeLayout and custom Views.
Assume one layout and two views:

```
<VRelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/grad">

<VView
                                        android:id="@+id/obj1"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<VView
                                        android:id="@+id/obj2"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                                   </VRelativeLayout>
```

In this example `obj1` is in front. Not `obj2`. Futher more, if I switch the arrangement (`obj1` after`obj2`)  in XML  nothing changes. Why? Is the only idea is to use `View.bringToFront()` in the code? Is this a bug?

Comment: please be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In android RelativeLayout, objects are stacked according to which is defined first. From that definition, android:id="@+id/obj2" is in front. To swap visibility, you can call setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) or setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) on either views. Hope this help.